Fourier sine Series of a nonperiodic function
hello there I was wondering if someone could please check my work and see if my solution has any flaws or not, thanks in advance,
Question: assuming $L=1$, find the sine Fourier series corresponding $f(x)$:
$$
\begin{gather}
\large \displaystyle 
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\quad if\quad 0 \le x\le \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \\
x\quad if\quad \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\le x\le 1
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
$$
My work: since function $\large f(x)$ is not periodic originally we have to create an odd periodic function with period $T=2L=2$ and then restrict the Fourier series expansion of the $\large F(x)$ (I'll call the new function $\large F(x)$ from now on) to the domain of the original function $\large f(x)$ and since the function $\large F(x)$ is an odd function it'll result in the Fourier series of the function having sine form:
$$
\begin{gather}
\large \displaystyle 
b_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sin (nx)\,\text{d}x \\ \\
\large \displaystyle
= 2\left[ \int_{0}^\frac{1}{2}\sin(n\pi x)\,\text{d}x+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}x\sin (n\pi x)\,\text{d}x \right] \\ \\
\large \displaystyle
= 2\left[ -\frac{1}{n\pi}\cos\left( \frac{n\pi}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n)+\frac{1}{2n\pi}\cos \left( \frac{n\pi}{2} \right)-\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}\sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{2} \right) \right] \\ \\
\large \displaystyle
b_{n}=
\begin{cases}
\large \displaystyle 
2\left[ \frac{1}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n)-\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}(-1)^n \right] \quad :\text{if n is odd} \\ \\
\large \displaystyle  
2\left[ \frac{1}{n\pi}(1-2(-1)^n)+\frac{1}{2n\pi}(-1)^n \right] \quad :\text{if n is even}
\end{cases} \\ \\
\large \displaystyle \widetilde{F}(x)\biggl]_{ x\in[0,1]}=\widetilde{f}(x) \\ \\
\large \displaystyle
\longrightarrow \quad =2\Biggl[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n)-\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}(-1)^n \right]\sin (n\pi x) \\ \\
\large \displaystyle  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n\pi}(1-2(-1)^n)+\frac{1}{2n\pi}(-1)^n \right]\sin (n\pi x) \Biggr]_{\textstyle x\in[0,1]}
\end{gather}
$$
Edit:My question seemed a bit vague so i'll try to ask it again in a more comprehensive way:
If $\large b_n$ have both odd (denoted as $\large b_{2n-1}$) and even (denoted as $\large b_{2n}$) parts am i allowed to do this:
$$
\large \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin (n\pi x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty [b_{2 n}+b_{2n-1}]\sin (n\pi x)
$$

No, $\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \sin(n\pi x) , dx$ should have been $\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 x, \sin(n\pi x) , dx$.

Thanks for the heads up, it was a typing error but the result is correct

Your last formula is incorrect since $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2 N} b_n\, \sin(n \pi x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left(b_{2 n-1}\, \sin((2 n-1) \pi x)+b_{2 n} \sin(2n \pi x)\right)$$ and while your initial formula for $b_n$ is correct, your subsequent formula for $f(x)$ is incorrect and should be equivalent to $$f(x)=2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2 \pi (2 n-1)+(-1)^n}{(\pi-2 n \pi)^2}\, \sin((2 n-1) \pi x)-\frac{(-1)^n}{4 n \pi}\, \sin(2 n \pi x)\right).$$

Thank you very much for your help, so to be clear what my solution lacked was that for odd and even parts of the coefficient $b_n$ I must multiply it by the corresponding base function (in this case $\sin n\pi x$) in order to create odd and even parts of Fourier approximation of $f(x)$, am I right?

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if the term is $a_m, \sin(m \pi x)$ when $m$ is odd and $c_m, \sin(m\pi x)$ when $m$ is even, then when $m$ is odd you evaluate the first term at $m=2 n-1$, and when $m$ is even you evaluate the second term at $m=2 n$.

Ok I get it now thanks
